# Open an app on google play when user click the hyperlink provided on the textview

Tags: android

Below is the code that i used to open an app on the google paly.

```
    final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(tag,"Message ="+e);

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    }
```

I have provided the hyperlink at the last of the text of the textview.how i can open an app on the google paly when user click on the hyperlink.

Comment: You can use a button. Set the code above to onlick listener of the button

Comment: hi ashish please have a look on the given answer , is it helpful to you??

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code in xml

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="<market_url>"
    android:id="@+id/openPlaystore"
    android:autoLink="all"
    android:linksClickable="true">
</TextView>
```

OR

Add `OnClickListener` to the textview

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.openPlaystore);
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(tag,"Message ="+e);

                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an app where I do the same... I use this code:

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView)v;
        if(! (tv.getSelectionStart()==-1 && tv.getSelectionEnd()==-1))
            // Fired only when you touch the part of the text that is hyperlinked 
            // do something
    }
```

Note that this works ONLY if you already successfully have your TextView display the hyperlink. Also, you usually don't need any code, since a hyperlink is resolved automatically by the TextView, but this code allows you to do additional processing.